# Pegar os 3 primeiros resultados numa consulta mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

Estou recuperando dados do banco que seria "O indicador do indicado", só que pega todos até recuperar todos. O que eu preciso fazer é pegar só os 3 primeiros resultados.

E se der eu indicar quantos resultados eu quero pegar, ou seja, setar isso na função ou em alguma variavel e quando pegar o valor X da variavel, então ele para de buscar pois não tem mais necessidade.

Atualmente fiz essa função, mas está me retornando todos os dados certos, mas está retornando mais do que 3 e eu quero somente 3 por enquanto. Preciso pegar os 3 primeiros somente.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo');
$bd = mysql_select_db('cotas', $db);

$array = array();

function indicadores($id){

    global $array;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM indicadores WHERE id_indicado = '$id'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

        $fetch = mysql_fetch_object($query);

        $id = $fetch->id_indicador;

        $array[] = $id;

        indicadores($id);

    }
}

indicadores(10);

echo var_dump($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

Se eu entendi bem, basta você alterar sua SQL query.

Tente isto:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM indicadores WHERE id_indicado = '$id' LIMIT 3 ORDER BY id_indicado DESC");
```

Comment: pra melhorar use **order by id_indicado desc** para pegar o ultimo registro inserido no seu **BD**

Comment: Esqueci deste detalhe, obrigado por comentar.

Comment: Você não precisa de recursividade para resolver isso, creio que essa query seja o suficiente.

Comment: Não deu certo. Ele me retorna um array `empty` creio que é porque ele re-executa a função até achar o último indicador.

Comment: tente **if(count($query)>0)**

Answer (score 1):

Eu tomei a liberdade de fazer algumas mudanças nos seu código.
Observação, você não deveria usa mysql_, são funcões depreciadas e não vão funcionar mais em futuras versões do php. Use mysqli_.
Obs: Teste a query num phpmyadmin ou qualquer um que você tiver, para ver se está retornando dados, se a query está correta.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo');
$bd = mysqli_select_db($db, 'cotas');

function indicadores($id){

    global $db;

    $array = array();

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM indicadores WHERE id_indicado = '$id' ORDER BY id_indicador DESC LIMIT 3");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

        while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_object($query)){
            $id = $fetch->id_indicador;
            $array[] = $id;
        }

    }

    return $array;
}

$array = indicadores(10);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas modificações. Eu na verdade não uso `mysql`, uso `CodeIgniter`, fiz isso só na correria aqui rsrsrs. A questão de fazer com o seu código é que ele só me retornará os registros onde `id_indicado` é igual a 10. Eu na verdade preciso fazer o seguinte: Renato indicou Jorge, Então ganha 50%. Jorge indicou Luiz, Então Jorge ganha 50% e Renato 40%. Luiz indicou Bruno, Então Luiz ganha 50%, Jorge Ganha 40%, Renato Ganha 30.. E assim por diante. Só preciso saber os indicadores da pessoa indicada e ir subindo, tipo uma escada.

Comment: Entendi errado a descrição inicial. Desculpa.

Answer (score 0):

**RESOLVIDO**

Achei essa solução:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'vertrigo');
$bd = mysql_select_db('cotas', $db);

$array = array();

function indicadores($id, $niveis){

    global $array;

    if($niveis > 0){

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM indicadores WHERE id_indicado = '$id'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){

            $fetch = mysql_fetch_object($query);

            $id = $fetch->id_indicador;

            $array[] = $id;

            indicadores($id, $niveis-1);

        }

    }
}

indicadores(10, 3);

echo var_dump($array);
?>
```